# Random Forest Train / Test meaning

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, criterion='entropy', random_state=42)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

From this, I get:

- 1.0 accuracy on training set
- 0.6990116801437556 accuracy on test set

Since we're not setting the `max_depth`, it seems the trees are overfitting to the training data.

My question is: what does this tell us about the training data? Does the fact that it has reasonable accuracy imply that the test data is very like the training data and that's the only reason we're getting such an accuracy?

Comment: This question is way too broad. You dont describe about the data or the preprocessing (if any) you did on it, how is the data split into train and test etc. But even if you do so, this will be off-topic for stackoverflow because it does not fall into programming issues. You should add all the details and move this to [Cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify the max_depth of the tree, it grows until you have all pure nodes. So it is natural to overfit and correct/expected to have 100% (or rather high if the min_number of samples for node is not too large) accuracy on the training set.
This fact in not very insightful about the training set.

The fact that you are having a "such good" accuracy on the test set could indeed point out a similarity in the distribution of training/test set (that a one point it is expected if they are drawn from the same phenomenon) and that the tree has some degree of generalizability.

As general rule I would say that it is wrong to infer conclusion from a single result and when the training set is over-fitting. Additionally considering 0.69 accuracy a "good" accuracy is relative to the problem at hand. 30% of difference between training set and test set could be a huge gap in many applications.

In order to have a better understanding of your problem and more robust results it would be better to use a cross validation approach and a random forest.